# Trying to understand how eval(expr, envir = df) works

Tags: r, eval, tidyverse, rlang, expr

I have built a function which seems to work, but I don't understand why.

My initial problem was to take a data.frame which contains counts of a population and expand it to re-create the original population. This is easy enough if you know the column names in advance.

```
      library(tidyverse)

      set.seed(121)

      test_counts <- tibble(Population = letters[1:4], Length = c(1,1,2,1), 
         Number = sample(1:100, 4))

      expand_counts_v0 <- function(Length, Population, Number) { 
            tibble(Population = Population, 
                   Length = rep(Length, times = Number))

      }


      test_counts %>% pmap_dfr(expand_counts_v0) %>%   # apply it
                 group_by(Population, Length) %>%    # test it
                   summarise(Number = n()) %>%  
                   ungroup %>%
                  { all.equal(., test_counts)}
      # [1] TRUE
```

However, I wanted to generalise it to a function which didn't need to know at the column names of the data.frame, and I'm interested in NSE, so I wrote:

```
test_counts1 <- tibble(Population = letters[1:4], 
                 Length = c(1,1,2,1), 
                 Number = sample(1:100, 4),
                 Height = c(100, 50, 45, 90),
                 Width = c(700, 50, 60, 90)
               )


expand_counts_v1 <- function(df, count = NULL) { 
     countq <- enexpr(count)
     names <- df %>% select(-!!countq) %>% names 
     namesq <- names %>% map(as.name)

     cols <- map(namesq, ~ expr(rep(!!., times = !!countq))
          ) %>% set_names(namesq)

      make_tbl <- function(...) {
                         expr(tibble(!!!cols)) %>% eval(envir = df)
      }

      df %>% pmap_dfr(make_tbl)
}
```

But, when I test this function it seems to duplicate rows 4 times:

```
   test_counts %>% expand_counts_v1(count = Number) %>% 
                   group_by(Population, Length) %>%
                   summarise(Number = n()) %>%
                   ungroup %>%
                   { sum(.$Number)/sum(test_counts$Number)}
   # [1] 4
```

This lead me to guess a solution, which was

```
   expand_counts_v2 <- function(df, count = NULL) { 
             countq <- enexpr(count)
             names <- df %>% select(-!!countq) %>% names 
             namesq <- names %>% map(as.name)

             cols <- map(namesq, ~ expr(rep(!!., times = !!countq))
              ) %>% set_names(namesq)

              make_tbl <- function(...) {
                          expr(tibble(!!!cols)) %>% eval(envir = df)
       }

      df %>% make_tbl
   }
```

This seems to work:

```
 test_counts %>% expand_counts_v2(count = Number) %>% 
                 group_by(Population, Length) %>%
                 summarise(Number = n()) %>%
                 ungroup %>%
                { all.equal(., test_counts)}
 # [1] TRUE 

  test_counts1 %>% expand_counts_v2(count = Number) %>% 
                      group_by(Population, Length, Height, Width) %>%
                      summarise(Number = n()) %>%
                      ungroup %>%
                    { all.equal(., test_counts1)}
   # [1] TRUE
```

But I don't understand why. How is it evaluating for each row, even though I'm not using pmap anymore? The function needs to be applied to each row in order to work, so it must be somehow, but I can't see how it's doing that.

**EDIT**

After Artem's correct explanation of what was going on, I realised I could do this

```
expand_counts_v2 <- function(df, count = NULL) { 
      countq <- enexpr(count)
      names <- df %>% select(-!!countq) %>% names 
      namesq <- names %>% map(as.name)

      cols <- map(namesq, ~ expr(rep(!!., times = !!countq))
                  ) %>% set_names(namesq)

    expr(tibble(!!!cols)) %>% eval_tidy(data = df)
}
```

Which gets rid of the unnecessary mk_tbl function. However, as Artem said, that is only really working because rep is vectorised. So, it's working, but not by re-writing the _v0 function and pmapping it, which is the process I was trying to replicate. Eventually, I discovered, rlang::new_function and wrote:

```
expand_counts_v3 <- function(df, count = NULL) { 
      countq <- enexpr(count)
      names <- df %>% select(-!!countq) %>% names 
      namesq <- names %>% map(as.name)

      cols <- map(namesq, ~ expr(rep(!!., times = !!countq))
                  ) %>% set_names(namesq)

      all_names <- df %>% names %>% map(as.name) 
    args <- rep(0, times = length(all_names)) %>% as.list %>% set_names(all_names)

    correct_function <- new_function(args,     # this makes the function as in _v0
                                     expr(tibble(!!!cols))  )
    pmap_dfr(df, correct_function)     # applies it as in _v0
}
```

which is longer, and probably uglier, but works the way I originally wanted.

Comment: I urge you to avoid dots in names: first off, keep it consistent; since you already use underscores, use these exclusively. Secondly, using dots in names has a specific meaning in the context of S3 method lookup, and using dots independently from that leads to confusion.

Comment: Thank you Konrad. I'll update the names now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in `eval( envir = df )`, which exposes the entire data frame to `make_tbl()`. Notice that you never use `...` argument inside `make_tbl()`. Instead, the function effectively computes the equivalent of

```
with( df, tibble(Population = rep(Population, times = Number), 
                 Length = rep(Length, times=Number)) )
```

regardless of what arguments you provide to it. When you call the function via `pmap_dfr()`, it essentially computes the above four times (once for each row) and concatenates the results by-row, resulting in the duplication of entries you've observed. When you remove `pmap_dfr()`, the function is called once, but since `rep` is itself vectorized (try doing `rep( test_counts$Population, test_counts$Number )` to see what I mean), `make_tbl()` computes the entire result in one go.

Comment: Thank you Artem, you explained it brilliantly. I'm just going to add some new versions I made, after reading your explanation.